# UITableViewCell setSelected:animated having no effect when animated

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I've got a view controller on iPad with three UITableViews on it.  They all have `dataSource` and `delegate` set to the VC.  In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in the VC, I do this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"Cell: %@", cell);
[cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
```

It logs the correct cell (non-nil), but the cell always stays selected until another cell in the same table is selected.  If I pass `NO` for `animated`, it works fine.  What's going on?  Why won't the cell animate its deselection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` to get the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: That works.  Why would that work and the `UITableViewCell` call not work?

Comment: The tableview must be responsible for maintaining the selection state of all its cells. The UITableViewCell method is only used to tell the cell how to render itself